# React-pro-sidebar Submenu not showing when Sidebar is collapsed

Tags: reactjs, sidebar, react-sidebar

The react-pro-sidebar package allows for collapsing the Sidebar but once its collapsed I cannot access the Submenu items. I have attached some example code

```
import {
  Sidebar,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  useProSidebar,
  SubMenu
 } from "react-pro-sidebar";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const { collapseSidebar, toggleSidebar } = useProSidebar();

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%" }}>
      <Sidebar breakPoint="md">
        <Menu>
          <SubMenu label="With Submenu">
            <MenuItem>Help</MenuItem>
          </SubMenu>
          <MenuItem> Calendar</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem> E-commerce</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </Sidebar>
      <main>
        <button onClick={() => collapseSidebar()}>Collapse</button>
        <button onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}>Toggle</button>
        <div>{children}</div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-nnv2vk?file=/src/Layout.js)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug and has been resolved by the developer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).